# Solve doesn't work in my problem and I don't understand why

Tags: equation-solving

I need to use solve to take all integers are semi integers that verifies a set of conditions.

I took the most simple example that cause my problem :

Here are the functions that details the conditions :

For a triplet (x,y,z),

I have to verify the following inequalities and equalities :

[image: Conditions of a triplet]

As you can see, I admit integer **or** semi integer solutions.

As you can see, the triplet (1/2,j4,J) is a valid solution of my system :[image]

Whereas, when I put the "1/2" into an unknown variable and I ask mathematica to find it : it doesn't work.[image]

Could you help me to find what doesn't work ?

I think it is linked with the semi integer condition because in some other case, when the solution of the unknown variable was an integer, mathematica found it.

(I prefered to put screenshoot whereas copy paste from mathematica because in the last case it was barely lisible)

Comment: We also don't see the problem since you haven't it formulated at all.

Comment: I don't totally agree but ok I will clarify my message

Comment: I edited it :) !

Comment: Convert to InputForm, copy and paste, and convert to code blocks.

Comment: Probably I misunderstood you but I wrote InputForm[my expression] on mathematica and it doesn't really improve the display if I do a copy/paste

Comment: See [`here`](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site)

Comment: Yes thank you i will take a look !

Answer (score 2):

Using your previously shown output, parentheses with arguments to [`Element`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Element.html), and [`FindInstance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html) rather than [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html)

```
FindInstance[{Abs[-(9/2) + k4] <= 5, 
  5 <= 9/2 + k4, (19/2 + k4) ∈ Integers, 
  k4 ∈ Integers || (1/2 + k4 ∈ Integers), 
  Abs[k4 - k6] <= 3/2, 3/2 <= k4 + k6, (3/2 + k4 + k6) ∈ Integers, 
  k4 ∈ Integers || (1/2 + k4) ∈ Integers, 
  k6 ∈ Integers || (1/2 + k6) ∈ Integers, Abs[6 - k6] <= 5, 
  5 <= 6 + k6, k6 ∈ Integers, 
  k6 ∈ Integers || (1/2 + k6) ∈ Integers}, {k4, k6}, 10]

(*  {{k4 -> 1/2, k6 -> 1}, {k4 -> 1/2, k6 -> 2}, {k4 -> 5/2, k6 -> 1}, {k4 -> 5/2,
   k6 -> 2}, {k4 -> 5/2, k6 -> 3}, {k4 -> 5/2, k6 -> 4}, {k4 -> 19/2, 
  k6 -> 8}, {k4 -> 19/2, k6 -> 9}, {k4 -> 19/2, k6 -> 10}, {k4 -> 19/2, 
  k6 -> 11}}  *)
```

Comment: Awesome thank you. Could you explain me why FindInstance is better than Solve here ? I checked the documentation but I didn't found an answer to this

Comment: Also, it seems to be necessary to tell him how much solution we want. But I don't initially know how much solutions I have, I just know I have a finite number of them.

Comment: @StarBucK - Because `Solve` returns a warning "Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve." You can often help `Solve` by bounding the range of the variables, e.g., add to list of conditions `0 <= k4 <= 10`. However, that also warns that "Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables."